# If not exists then exit + cmd

Tags: cmd, dos

i try to make a loop in a .cmd file.

If test.txt is not exists then i will kill the cmd process.

```
@echo off
if not exists test.txt goto exit
```

But this code doesn't work and i don't know how to make a loop every 2 seconds.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The command is called `exist`, not *exists*:

```
if not exist test.txt goto :exit
echo file exists
:exit
```

About your loop:
I am not 100% sure, but I think there is no *sleep* or *wait* command in Windows. You can google for *sleep* to find some freeware. Another possibility is to use a *ping*:

```
ping localhost -n 3 >NUL
```

*EDIT:*
The [Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9D467A69-57FF-4AE7-96EE-B18C4790CFFD&displaylang=en) contains a *sleep*.
See [here](http://malektips.com/dos0017.html) for more information, too

Comment: maybe improve this answer to exit with a non-zero exit code?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to wait some seconds use standard **CHOICE** command. This sample code check if file exist each two seconds. The loop ends if file exists:

```
@ECHO OFF    
:CHECKANDWAITLABEL
IF EXIST myfile.txt GOTO ENDLABEL
choice /C YN /N /T 2 /D Y /M "waiting two seconds..."
GOTO CHECKANDWAITLABEL 

:ENDLABEL
```

Comment: there is also a `timeout` command. But both `choice` and `timeout` are not available in all windows-versions. `Ping` is.

Answer (score 1):

exit is a key word in DOS/Command Prompt - that's why goto exit
doesn't work.

Using if not exist "file name" exit dumps you out of that batch file.
That's fine if exiting the batch file is what you want.

If you want to execute some other instructions before you exit, change the label to something like :notfound then you can goto notfound
and execute some other instructions before you exit.

(this is just a clarification to one of the examples)

Answer (score 0):

Using the following:

```
if not exist "file name" goto exit
```

Results in:

```
The system cannot find the batch label specified - exit
```

However using the same command without "goto" works, as follows:

```
if not exist "file name" exit
```